# check deposit question

Tags: check

Someone sent me a signed check and they spelled out my name and put the date on it, but forgot to put in the dollar amount in both fields. It is a weekly recurring check amount. I put in the $500.00 and the Five Hundred and 00/100. Can I get in trouble for this?

Comment: How much were you supposed to get? When you go to deposit the check, the teller might notice the different hand-writing and raise a question, or maybe not. The forgetful "Someone" might raise a stink at _their_ bank if you were supposed to get less than the $500 you wrote in but how far their bank will consider the claim depends on any number of things including how large a customer that "Someone" is.

Comment: I am supposed to get $500.00 on every check every week. I only put in exactly the amount that I am entitled to.

Comment: If they wrote out the amount, then you are fine and even without the numeric entry, they will accept it. However, if nothing is in either field and you put it in there, the fact is that if they made the check to you, signed it, you can pretty much put whatever you want there and be fine. Its the concept of a blank check. Of course you don't want to abuse this snafu and if you are taking only what you were entitled and was intended to be paid to you, then you will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, just tell the person that sent the check what happened and that you are filling in the proper amount of $500. I can't imagine they would have a problem with it.

If that's not possible, and if you know the check was supposed to be for $500 and that's what the issuer expects, write it in. Me, I would have no problem filling in the proper amount and depositing the check.